# Is using the args syntax in Python multiprocessing always necessary?

Tags: python, syntax, python-multiprocessing, args

I am learning up on methods of multiprocessing in Python and have found myself with a question. Consider the following example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(n):
    print('worker %d' % n)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = mp.Process(target = worker, args = (i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

This is how the documentation that I am following uses `Process`.

Is it necessary to user `args = (i,)`? I have never seen this syntax in Python before and it seems strange. I tested, and this works exactly the same:

`p = mp.Process(target = worker(i))`

Is there any reason that I should avoid that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can grab the sys.argv[n] at a specific location

Comment: You could also use args = [i], the main requirement being that it must be unpackable with * to an argument list, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists and https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick way for you to prove that it isn't the same thing.  Change your `worker(i)` function to this:

```
import time

def worker(n):
    print('worker %d' % n)
    time.sleep(1)
    return
```

When you call this the first way, you'll notice that you still get all 5 prints at the same time right at the beginning.  When you do it your second way, you'll see that you get all 5 prints staggered, with a second between each one.

Think about what you're trying to set up: 5 independent processes are each being started up at about the same time, each print at about the same time, and then each wait about a second, but the total time elapsed is only a little more than a second.  This is what you want to have happen.

Here's the key point: `target = worker` sets `target` to be the `worker` function, and `args = (i,)` sets `args` to be a single element tuple containing `i`.  On the other hand, `target = worker(i)` calls `worker(i)` and sets `target` to be the value that the function returns, in this case `None`.  You're not really using `multiprocessing` at all when you do it the second way.  If you have a really time consuming task that you want to split across multiple processes, then you'll see no improvement when it's done the second way.

Basically, anytime you have `func(args)`, you're going to be *calling* the function and getting its return value, whereas when you pass `func` and `args` separately, you allow the `multiprocessing` package to work its magic and make those function calls on independent processes.  Setting the target to be `func(args)` will just call the function in the main process, losing you any benefits from multiprocessing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is for declaring tuple vars (without, it's an int, a string, a float…) but not an immutable:

```
>>> i = 4
>>> k = (i,)
>>> type(k)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> k=(i)
>>> type(k)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: You haven't (and I did not vote you down), but your answer didn't answer my question fully. I was asking the purpose in separating the arguments from the function name, I didn't realize what it meant to pass a function itself rather than the result of a function. But you addressed differences in data types. And people on StackOverflow are always ready to downvote for no good reason.

Comment: @jphollowed: you're right, I have responded only to a part of the question. And yes, down-vote seems easier than up-vote. :-)